# How can I fill empty DataFrame based on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I have following dataframe called `condition`:

```
     [0]   [1]   [2]   [3]
1     0     0     1     0     
2     0     1     0     0     
3     0     0     0     1     
4     0     0     0     1
```

For easier reproduction:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
n=4
t=3   
condition = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,0, 1], [0,0,0, 1]], columns=['0','1', '2', '3'])
condition.index=np.arange(1,n+1)
```

Further I have several dataframes that should be filled in a `foor loop`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([],index = range(1,n+1),columns= range(t+1) ) #NaN DataFrame
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([],index = range(1,n+1),columns= range(t+1) ) 
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(3,index = range(1,n+1),columns= range(t+1) )

for i,t in range(t,-1,-1):
    
    if condition[t]==1: 
        df.loc[:,t] = df_3.loc[:,t]**2
        df_2.loc[:,t]=0
    elif (condition == 0 and no 1 in any column after t)
        df.loc[:,t] = 2.5
       ....
    else:
        df.loc[:,t] = 5
        df_2.loc[:,t]= df.loc[:,t+1]
```

I am aware that this for loop is not correct, but what I wanted to do, is to check elementwise `condition` (recursevly) and if it is 1 (in condition) to fill dataframe `df` with squared valued of `df_3`. If it is 0 in `condition`, I should differentiate two cases.

> In the first case, there are no 1 after 0 (row 1 and 2 in `condition`) then df = 2.5

> Second case, there was 1 after and fill `df` with 5 (row 3 and 4)

So the dataframe `df` should look something like this

```
     [0]   [1]   [2]   [3]
1     5     5     9    2.5     
2     5     9    2.5   2.5     
3     5     5     5     9     
4     5     5     5     9
```

The code should include `for loop`.
Thanks!

Comment: You may find success with [`np.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).

Comment: why would your final result have different values for each row? In your code you do `df.loc[:,t] = 2.5` which assigns the same value to all the rows in one column

Comment: @Z Li I know the code doesn't work as I want, but is just one of the many options that I tried, so therefore I left it here. The result presented is what I wanted to get at the end. @owen I will try with np.select(), I already did with np.where()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but based on your desired output you can do this with only masking operations (which is more efficient than looping over the rows anyway). Your code could look like this:

```
is_one = condition.astype(bool)
is_after_one = (condition.cumsum(axis=1) - condition).astype(bool)

df = pd.DataFrame(5, index=condition.index, columns=condition.columns)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(2.5, index=condition.index, columns=condition.columns)
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(3, index=condition.index, columns=condition.columns)

df.where(~is_one, other=df_3 * df_3, inplace=True)
df.where(~is_after_one, other=df_2, inplace=True)
```

which yields:

```
   0  1    2    3
1  5  5  9.0  2.5
2  5  9  2.5  2.5
3  5  5  5.0  9.0
4  5  5  5.0  9.0
```

EDIT after comment:

If you really want to loop explicitly over the rows and columns, you could do it like this with the same result:

```
n_rows = condition.index.size
n_cols = condition.columns.size

for row_index in range(n_rows):
    for col_index in range(n_cols):
        cond = condition.iloc[row_index, col_index]
        if col_index < n_cols - 1:
            rest_row = condition.iloc[row_index, col_index + 1:].to_list()
        else:
            rest_row = []
        if cond == 1:
            df.iloc[row_index, col_index] = df_3.iloc[row_index, col_index] ** 2
        elif cond == 0 and 1 not in rest_row:
            # fill whole row at once
            df.iloc[row_index, col_index:] = 2.5
            # stop iterating over the rest
            break
        else:
            df.iloc[row_index, col_index] = 5
            df_2.loc[:, col_index] = df.iloc[:, col_index + 1]
```

The result is the same, but this is much more inefficient and ugly, so I would not recommend it like this

Comment: van Vilet Thanks for sharing, but actually I have several conditional dataframes in a for loop with several formulas, so this wouldn't work in this setting. I will try to rethink how can I solve this. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, that is possible. But from your code it is not clear how you want it. What range of t are you supposed to look over? And you have a condition[t] == 1 en condition == 0 check which I don't understand you are trying to do. But the output can be reproduced with the masks, that's why I posted it. If you need a more loop like answer your should explain your conditional statements clearer

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I wasn't clear. I wanted to iterate over each column t=3 (for column 3,2,1 and 0). The problem is that each row is different due to difference in 'condition', so I guess that I should also iterate over rows (I am not sure, as I just started learning Python).  So fill the 'df' with df_3^2 if the condition is 1, 2.5 if the 0 is_after_one , and if 0 comes before 1, fill the 'df' with 5. And the solution should look like the one that you get with mask.